# MVC 5 Identity Login and "Remember Me" - What needs to be done to get it set up?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I have the following code in my Account controller:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        ApplicationUser user = null;

        // In order to authenticate, we need a user name. Let's find it based on the email address.
        user = await this.UserManager.FindByEmailAsync(model.Email);
        if (user != null)
            user = await this.UserManager.FindAsync(user.UserName, model.Password);

        if (user != null && user.EmailConfirmed)
        {
            await this.SignInAsync(user, model.RememberMe);
            return this.RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Either your username or password is invalid, or your email address has not yet been confirmed");
        }
    }

    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    return this.View(model);
}
```

It appears that "Remember Me" is already being handled with this snippet of code:

```
        if (user != null && user.EmailConfirmed)
        {
            await this.SignInAsync(user, model.RememberMe);
            return this.RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
        }
```

However, it doesn't seem to be working reliably. Is there anything else that needs to be done to set up "Remember Me?"

Comment: fyi there are some known bugs https://aspnetidentity.codeplex.com/workitem/2319

Comment: Haven't ever run into any issues with Remember Me since using Identity 2.2.1. What's the behavior? Is the cookie not being regenerated when you close/reopen browser window?

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(user.UserName, model.RememberMe);
```